# qapplication multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance, qapplication

I want to create a class that inherits from two classes, one of them being QApplication.

```
class TheApp : public QApplication, public MyApp
{
public:
   TheApp(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    : QApplication(argc,argv), MyApp(argc,argv) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication App(argc,argv);
    App.exec();
}
```

When I run, I have a segmentation fault. When I rewrite the code likes this, it works:

```
class TheApp : public MyApp
{
public:
   TheApp(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    : MyApp(argc,argv) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication App(argc,argv);
    TheApp App2(argc,argv);
    App.exec();
}
```

It seems impossible to inherit from QApplication and another class. Has anyone an idea why it doesn't work ?

Thanks.

Comment: `MyApp` inherits `QObject`?? Otherwise all classes that inherit from `QObject` shall contains `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: How about `MyApp` inheriting `QApplication` and `TheApp` inheriting `MyApp`?

Comment: @eferion: That is not true. The `Q_OBJECT` is required only when using slots and/or signals in that class. See Qt docs.

Comment: @Goggie I know but, are you sure `App.exec( )` doesn't use signals and slots internally?

Comment: @eferion: So what if it does? What is the problem about it?

Comment: @Googie It is primarily for consistency... if a class inherits `QObject`, put `Q_OBJECT` macro to allow moc generate the metadata. But this is not the problem. I think `MyApp` inherits `QObject` and classes shall not inherit `QObject` twice or more times because signals and slots are indexed by numeric values and can collide between them.

Comment: Adding Q_OBJECT doesn't change anything.